# Sample size for validation of questionnaire

Tags: sample-size, survey, validation, psychometrics

how to determine sample size for a questionnaire validation study in a certain population. the questionnaire has underwent psychometric validation before this.

Answer (score 0):

The question implies a measure of reliability, read the link to [Cronbach's alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach%27s_alpha), and use that. Make sure that you have enough data to be reliable ($\alpha\geq0.8$).